# Roots of polynomial with respect to 0 degree term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I was looking for some conditions for a polynomial of a special form to have at least one positive eigenvalue.

$$
p(s) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(s+\gamma_i) \ + (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i 
$$

where the constants $\gamma_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are always positive. For the 2 dimensional case, the case is simple, but what could be a good approach to find a lower bound on the second product such that the polynomial has at least one root with positive real part?

The problem is related to the eigenvalues of the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -\gamma_1  &\dots & 0 & \alpha_1\\
 \alpha_2 & -\gamma_2 &  \dots & 0 \\
0 & \dots & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0&\alpha_n & -\gamma_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Reading some other questions here on StackExchange I thought the Gershgorin circle theorem could be useful but it only gives estimates of the region that contains the eigenvalues. One first necessary condition would be to have $\alpha_i > \gamma_i$, but it is not sufficient...

Comment: It is well known if you suppose that all the roots of $p$ are real. But I feel this is not the case you are considering, right?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? (Which result would I refer to)?
Anyway, is there any condition on the entries such that the roots are real?

Comment: At the high school I learned that if a polynomial has only real roots , the number of its positive zeroes la equal to the sign changes of  its (ordered) coefficients. I do not know of it is studied everywhere, but if I well rember is easy to prove using derivatives

Comment: For example, consider $p(x)=x^3-2x^2-5x+6$, the signs of its coefficients are $+, -, -, +$. There are two sign changes and then $p$ has two positive roots.

Comment: I see, but I don't think I can assume that all roots are real.